# Securing tomcat7 - Disabling RC4 does not work

Tags: ssl, tomcat7

I'm trying to secure my tomcat 7 setup. I have currently two problems here comes my first one:

I use basically the default configuration, I just extended the ssl configuration to get an A rating on [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).

My problem is that I want to disable RC4 since it is insecure, so I added the cipher suites which I trust (well it is the [list of Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Modern_compatibility)) it ends with `!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK` which means AFIK that those algorithm should not been used. But RC4 is still used here is my full configuration (without comments):

```xml
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" SSLHonorCipherOrder="true"
               SSLDisableCompression="true" SSLCipherSuite="ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK"
               SSLCertificateChainFile="/root/ca.crt"
               SSLCACertificatePath="/etc/ssl/certs"
               keystoreFile="/path/to/keystore" keystorePass="pwd" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

If you know what I'm doing wrong please inform me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've formatted your cipher suite list as if you were using APR / OpenSSL, but are still configured to use the NIO connector, which will rely on Java to do the connection, and as such needs that format for the cipher list.  Put your preferred suites into a comma delimited list (no classes of suites, only explicit configurations), restart, and see if that doesn't resolve it for you.

Oracle Java 8 cipher names can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html

You can use this connector:

```xml
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" SSLHonorCipherOrder="true"
           SSLDisableCompression="true" ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
           keystoreFile="/path/to/keystore" keystorePass="pwd" />
```

Comment: I'm still playing with that. Do you know what `kEDH+AESGCM` does? about `ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-SHA256` that can been translated to `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` and `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`. The difference is `GCM` vs. `CBC` what does that mean? Some of those strings have just one translation and not both can this be a problem? How can `!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK` been translated? Is this even possible?

Comment: You have a long list of named ciphers as it is; I wouldn't try to translate the latter commands ("!anull:!des, etc.), as they don't apply in the Java / Tomcat world directly.  In short, they would provide rules for which ciphers to use, whereas Tomcat only allows explicit configuration.  Test with the list you have, and if you heed to for compatibility reasons, maybe add one or two more to the list.

CBC / GCM has to do with the message integrity.  Opinions vary, but my own is that GCM is better to use if available, though CBC is perfectly acceptable and generally needed for compatibility.